# Outputting item options from Cartthrob

Tags: cartthrob

I have set up a site for booking various conference events with each event represented by a product.

I am trying to output the booking options (set by the item_options) for each event.
The following works but with a couple of problems:

```
 <table>
    {exp:channel:entries channel="orders"} 
{if first_item} <tr><td>Order ID</td>{item_options}<td>{option_label}    </td>{/item_options} </tr>{/if} 
    {exp:cartthrob:order_items order_id="{entry_id}" entry_id="{8647}"}
  {if first_item} <tr><td>Order ID</td>{item_options}<td>{option_label}</td>{/item_options} </tr>{/if}   
   <tr><td>{order_id}</td>{item_options}<td>{option_value}</td>{/item_options} </tr> 

    {/exp:cartthrob:order_items}
    {/exp:channel:entries}
     </table>
```

I am encountering two issues:

1. The table heading is appearing for every row
2. The out put works ok if the item entry id is set directly (ie in this case 8647) but I would like to be able to allow the user to select an event on another page and have the entry id fed to the results via a segment. The following code does not work:

`{exp:cartthrob:order_items order_id="{entry_id}" entry_id="{segment_3}"}`

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks

EDIT: I managed to get the table header sorted by ysing the following code.

```
{exp:cartthrob:order_items entry_id="8646"} 
     {if item:first_item}
                <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
        <td>entry_id</td>
        <td>title</td>
        {item_options}
            <td>{option_label}</td>
            {/item_options}
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {/if}
    <tr>
        <td>{entry_id}</td>
   <td> {title}</td>
    {item_options}
    <td>{option_value} </td>
    {/item_options} 
</tr>
     {if item:last_item}


                        </tbody> 
  </table> 
                  {/if}
    {/exp:cartthrob:order_items}
```

The Issue of not being able to output a specific list of order items using the  entry_id="{segment_3}" still remains.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such conditional as `first_item` in `exp:channel:entries`.
You need to do this:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="orders"}
  {if count == 1}...{/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

But you are repeating the first row inside and outside of the `exp:cartthrob:order_items` tag, so it will be shown anyway.

As for the `order_id` in `exp:cartthrob:order_items`, what does "doesn't work" mean? Nothing gets displayed? Have you tried adding `parse="inward"`?

Comment: {exp:cartthrob:order_items entry_id="8646"} 
   {if item:first_item}
              <table>
      <thead>
      <tr>
      <td>entry_id</td>
      <td>title</td>
      {item_options}
       <td>{option_label}</td>
       {/item_options}
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      {/if}
  <tr>
   <td>{entry_id}</td>
    <td> {title}</td>
     {item_options}
     <td>{option_value} </td>
     {/item_options} 
 </tr>
   {if item:last_item}


                         </tbody> 
   </table> 
                   {/if}
     {/exp:cartthrob:order_items}

Comment: sorry - ignore previous comment! As you can see by my update to the question I have solved the table header issue. In terms of outputting the order info for a specific entry - if I add the entry_id directly into the code I get a list of all the bookings made but if I try entry_id="{segment_3}" parse="inward" nothing gets displayed.